# How to fix the duplicate of the form submission in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, form-submit

I am working on fixing the defaulte search form in wordpress.
I am just setting some filters to make the user choose then click ok to search with filter and everything worked fine except the tags checkbox.

I tried all the these:
tag (string) – use tag slug.
tag_id (int) – use tag id.
tag__and (array) – use tag ids.
tag__in (array) – use tag ids.
tag__not_in (array) – use tag ids.
tag_slug__and (array) – use tag slugs.
tag_slug__in (array) – use tag slugs.

but the results are the same.

My search form in searchform.php

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="skytube-search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <input type="search" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for what you want...', 'aldoustech' ); ?>" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" onkeyup="search()">
    <label for="order">الترتيب حسب التاريخ</label>
    <select name="order">
        <option <?php if ($_GET['order'] == 'ASC') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="ASC">الأقدم</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['order'] == 'DESC') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="DESC">الأحدث</option>
    </select>
    <label for="posts_per_page">عدد النتائج المعروضة</label>
    <select name="posts_per_page">
        <option <?php if ($_GET['posts_per_page'] == '10') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="10">10</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['posts_per_page'] == '50') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="50">50</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['posts_per_page'] == '100') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    <label for="category_name">التصنيف</label>
    <select name="category_name">
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == '') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="">
            الكل
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'مسلسلات-أنمي') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="مسلسلات-أنمي">
            مسلسلات أنمي
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'مسلسلات آسيوية') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="مسلسلات آسيوية">
            مسلسلات آسيوية
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'مسلسلات-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="مسلسلات-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون">
            مسلسلات الأنيميشن و الكرتون
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'أفلام-أنمي') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="أفلام-أنمي">
            أفلام أنمي
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'أفلام آسيوية') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="أفلام آسيوية">
            أفلام آسيوية
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'أفلام-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="أفلام-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون">
            أفلام الأنيميشن و الكرتون
        </option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'orderby' => 'name'
            ) ) ) : 
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="' . $term->slug . '"' . (($_GET['tag'] ==  $term->slug)?'checked':"") . '> ' . $term->name;
                endforeach;
            endif;
        ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'aldoustech' ); ?>">
</form>
```

When I choose some of the filters then hit search the url became something like that.

```
http://localhost:8080/wordpress/?s=&order=ASC&posts_per_page=10&cat=3
```

and when I choose one tag the url will look like this

```
http://localhost:8080/wordpress/?s=&order=ASC&posts_per_page=10&cat=3&tag=hello
```

Both urls are good but when I choose more than one tag the url became like that.

```
http://localhost:8080/wordpress/?s=&order=ASC&posts_per_page=10&cat=3&tag=hello&tag=bye
```

You can see the duplicate of the `tag=hello&tag=bye`

This form don't get the result that I want because it must be like this:

`tag=hello+bye`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me.

```
// In footer.php
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // Get the selected tags in search
                function getTheCheckedTags() {
                    var items = document.getElementsByName('tags');
                    var selectedItems = "";
                    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                        if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true)
                            selectedItems+=items[i].value+",";
                    }
                    document.getElementsByName('tag')[0].value = selectedItems;
                }
                document.getElementById('searchform').addEventListener('change', getTheCheckedTags);
            </script>
// Don't forget to call the Jquery before this code.
            <script>
            $('#searchform').submit( function(){
              var tags = $('.tags');
              tags.prop('disabled', true);
            });
            </script>
```

```
// In searchform.php
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="skytube-search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <input type="search" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for what you want...', 'aldoustech' ); ?>" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" onkeyup="search()">
    <label for="order">الترتيب حسب التاريخ</label>
    <select name="order">
        <option <?php if ($_GET['order'] == 'ASC') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="ASC">الأقدم</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['order'] == 'DESC') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="DESC">الأحدث</option>
    </select>
    <label for="posts_per_page">عدد النتائج المعروضة</label>
    <select name="posts_per_page">
        <option <?php if ($_GET['posts_per_page'] == '10') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="10">10</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['posts_per_page'] == '50') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="50">50</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['posts_per_page'] == '100') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    <label for="category_name">التصنيف</label>
    <select name="category_name">
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == '') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="">
            الكل
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'مسلسلات-أنمي') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="مسلسلات-أنمي">
            مسلسلات أنمي
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'مسلسلات آسيوية') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="مسلسلات آسيوية">
            مسلسلات آسيوية
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'مسلسلات-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="مسلسلات-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون">
            مسلسلات الأنيميشن و الكرتون
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'أفلام-أنمي') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="أفلام-أنمي">
            أفلام أنمي
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'أفلام آسيوية') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="أفلام آسيوية">
            أفلام آسيوية
        </option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['category_name'] == 'أفلام-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="أفلام-الأنيميشن-و-الكرتون">
            أفلام الأنيميشن و الكرتون
        </option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'orderby' => 'name'
            ) ) ) : 
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                    echo '<input class="tags" type="checkbox" name="tags" value="' . $term->slug . '"' . (($_GET['tag'] ==  $term->slug)?'checked':"") . '> ' . $term->name;
                endforeach;
            endif;
        ?>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="tag" value=""> نوع
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'aldoustech' ); ?>">
</form>
```

I made the code by myself and I have solved the problem by using the javascript to add the checked checkboxes to another textfield then sends the textfield with it's data via the form.